# how do i fix type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, localhost

i was trying to connect my flutter app to my own api using localhost, i actually got a bit of the data in my debug console but it stoped halfway and showing
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'` error, like this:
[image]

and the list isnt showing in my aplication homepage, how do i fix this? this is my code:

**my repository code**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:medreminder/TipsAndTricks/models/tips_model.dart';

class Repo{
  final _baseUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/tips';

  Future getData() async{
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_baseUrl));

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        print(response.body);
        Iterable it = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<Tips> tips = it.map((e) => Tips.fromJson(e)).toList();
        return tips;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**my model class**

```
class Tips {
  final String title;
  final String desc;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String source;

  const Tips({
    required this.title,
    required this.desc,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.source,
  });

  factory Tips.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Tips(
      source: json['source'],
      desc: json['desc'],
      title: json['title'],
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl']
    );
  }
}
```

**and my homepage**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/TipsAndTricks/models/tips_model.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/TipsAndTricks/screens/tips_details.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/TipsAndTricks/tips_repo.dart';

class TipsList extends StatefulWidget {
  const TipsList({super.key});

  @override
  State<TipsList> createState() => _TipsListState();
}

class _TipsListState extends State<TipsList> {
  List<Tips> listTips = [];
  Repo repo = Repo();

  getData() async {
    listTips = await repo.getData();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.grey[600]:Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: ()=>Get.back(),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.grey
          ),
        ),
        title:  Text("Healthy Tips & Tricks", style: TextStyle(
          color: Get.isDarkMode?Colors.white:Colors.black
        ),),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listTips.length, 
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          Tips tips = listTips[index];
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(listTips[index].title),
              subtitle: Text(listTips[index].source),
              leading: Image.network(listTips[index].imageUrl),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TipsDetails(listTips[index])));
              },
            ),
          );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

if anyone know how to fix this, please help. it would mean so much to me. thankyou guys

Answer (score 1):

Response of your API call is json object, not json array (from what I see in your screenshot). So jsonDecode creates Map<String, dynamic> (_InternalLinkedHashMap in fact). You are assigning it to `Iterable it`, and Iterable is not subtype of Map.

Instead, You should access your "tips" field of json, which is array:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> apiRespose = jsonDecode(response.body);
Iterable<dynamic> it = apiRespose['tips'];
...
```

Comment: it doesnt show anymore error sir, but the listview still wont showup in my app. how do i fix this? thankyou

Comment: I am assuming that it is because you are not notifying State that it has new value, once async call fetching the data completes. To do this you need to wrap listTips field assignment with setState(). However it might be that at this moment widget might not be mounted yet. Best way to handle that is to change field to future and use FutureBuilder widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: can you answer with the source code please sir? thankyou

Comment: Please tell me what is the problem for you to change your code having my guidelines and I will be happy to help you.